# Opengl glScalef reset performance

Tags: performance, opengl

```
glScalef(0.5f, 0.5f, 0);
// do some things
glScalef(2.0f, 2.0f, 0);
```

Or..

```
glPushMatrix();
glScalef(0.5f, 0.5f, 0);
// do some things
glPopMatrix();
```

Which is better, performance wise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second one. Because the first one computes and multiplies a 4x4 matrix, while the second only writes and reads it. Note that OpenGL can be intelligent about it and only create/multiply a diagonal matrix. Nevertheless, you are comparing 3 floating point multiplications with 16 variable stores. If you are concerned about the difference in performance, you need to write a test.

Precision-wise, the second one is definitely better because due to whatever rounding error `0.5 * x * 2` might give a different value than `x`. This is why, even if the other method is slightly faster, this method is preferred.

Comment: No. A scale is a diagonal matrix requiring no full matrix multiplication. I doubt implementations will not use that fact. However, the matrices may be more complicated.

Comment: @StefanHanke, you are right. The implementation will definitely be intelligent about it. Nevertheless, push/pop saves floating point multiplications. I have edited my answer.